# removing all instances of a character and symbol from a string

Tags: node.js, string

I'm trying to remove all instances of `\n`, from a string in javascript. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

I tried 
`mystring = mystring.replace(/\n/g,'');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read MDN?

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\n/g, '');
```

PS. You don't need to put `i` flag which stands for *case insensitive*, since there is just one line break sign :)

If you mean you need to get rid of `\n\` literally then your regexp should be `/\\n/g` to remove the `string` `\n`.

Comment: I did not read MDN, but I tried that method and it did not work.

Comment: MDN is (or should be) your Bible as a Javascript programmer, if in doubt you can always check something there.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: Keep in mind that some signs are escaped in RegExp so to literally remove ` \ ` for instance you would need to escape it and make it a regular 'char', like ` \\ `

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `"` from your regex expression. You also do not need the "case insensitive" modifier, but just global (g). Use this instead.

`mystring = mystring.replace(/\n/g, '')`

And to be very verbose, you can replace all vertical whitespace characters with the following.

`mystring = mystring.replace(/[\n\r\v]/g, '')`

Comment: I attempted this and was unsuccessful.

Comment: Try running the following in a JavaScript console (like your browsers Dev Tools). ```"test\n test2\n\n test3 \n".replace(/[\n\r\v]/g, '')```. You should get ```"test test2 test3 "```

Comment: Okay I will give that a shot don't kniw why it won't seem to work on the string I'm working with